# jQuery - Run Function on several elements and change variable accordingly

Tags: jquery

I have a function that loads in content from a different page.  I'd like to be able to use the same function on different elements and load in content from different url's via a "changable" variable.

I set my variables:

```
var $banner1 = '/url1',
    $banner2 = '/url2',
    $banner3 = '/url3',
    $someUrl;
```

And I figured some form of IF statement would solve my problems?
Like this:

```
if ($('.banner-01').length > 0) {
        var $someUrl = $banner1;
    }

    if ($('.banner-02').length > 0) {
        var $someUrl = $banner2;
    }

    if ($('.banner-03').length > 0) {
        var $someUrl = $banner3;
    }
```

And then I run my function

```
$.fn.loadContent = function() {
        $('.info').each(function()({
            $(this).load($someUrl);
        });
    }

    $('.banner-01').loadContent();
    $('.banner-02').loadContent();
    $('.banner-03').loadContent();
```

**My Expected Outcome**

```
$('.banner-01 .info').load('/url1');
$('.banner-02 .info').load('/url2');
$('.banner-03 .info').load('/url3');
```

However, this isn't the case and I'm incredibly stuck.

Any help on this would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the url depends on the element's class you'll have to check the class each time you call the function, not just once.

Additionally $('.info') is targetting *all* .info elements, if you only want to target children of the banner then do $(this).find('.find'):

```
$.fn.loadContent = function() {
    var whichUrl = '';
    if($(this).hasClass('banner-01')){
        whichUrl = $banner1;
    }else if($(this).hasClass('banner-02')){
        whichUrl = $banner2;
    }else if($(this).hasClass('banner-03')){
        whichUrl = $banner3;
    }
    $(this).find('.info').each(function()({
        $(this).load(whichUrl);
    });
}
```